# PHP Filesystem Pagination

Tags: php, file, filesystems, pagination, glob

How does one paginate a large listing of files within a folder?

I can't see any functions in the PHP documentation that mention any way to specify an 'offset'. Both glob() and scandir() simply return all the files in the folder, and I'm afraid that won't be a good idea for a huge directory.

Is there any better way of doing this than simply going through all the files and chopping off the first X number of  files? Note that I would like to have options for recursive traversal and using a glob() pattern.

Edit: I've looked a lot at [LimitIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.limititerator.php), [GlobIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.globiterator.php) and [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php). They all seem nice but I have no idea where to even start if I was to combine them (The PHP SPL documentation is extremely sparse). I'm probably just over-thinking the problem.

Comment: How large is large? Did you try the SPL classes at all or are you stumped with where to start?

Comment: Currently the folder has about 2000 icons so Pagination is necessary. I tried working with the SPL Iterators but the documentation is just too sparse. My version of PHP also does not support GlobIterator, so I think I'll have to cook up my own version. Is it better to extend one of the existing iterators or manually implement one of the interfaces?

Comment: which version of PHP are you using? Cooking up a GlobIterator is not much trouble assuming familiarity with how these (filtering) iterators work. If you want to bounce thoughts back and forth here feel free, or you can email me (suffix @php.net to my username here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can paginate the results yourself, PHP returns a simple array, so you can keep a $offset and $limit variables so you know in which part of your array you are.

If you are in a web context, you can pass these around in GET parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Just to put some code to what Francisco Soto said, paginate manually

```
$limit = 10;
$offset = (isset($_GET['offset'])) ? $_GET['offset'] : 0;
$dir = scandir($path);
for ($i = $offset; $i < $offset+$limit; $i++) {
    echo $dir[$i] . "<br />";
}
echo "<br />";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($dir); $i++) {
    echo "<a href='?offset=" . ($i*$limit) . "'>{$i}</a>";
}
```

VERY rough, untested code.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. Directories are just another type of streams, and this is how the "seek" operator is defined:

```
static int php_plain_files_dirstream_rewind(php_stream *stream, off_t offset, int whence, off_t *newoffs TSRMLS_DC)
{
    rewinddir((DIR *)stream->abstract);
    return 0;
}
```

You see it's just a rewind. So you must read the first n entries to read entry n + 1. If you want to be more efficient, you can read the whole directory the first time and use it as a cache (store e.g. in the session). Once you've read all, you go to offset n+1 in the stored array.